# Convert class to fixed-length float array

Tags: c++

How can I convert the following class to a fixed-length float array?

```
class Vertex
{
public:
    Vertex( float x = 0,
            float y = 0,
            float z = 0)
    : x(x), y(y), z(z) {}

    float x, y, z;
};
```

For example, I would like to use it like so:

```
Vertex v(0, 1, 0);
float arr[3] = v; // How to convert here?
```

Thanks!

---

**Edit:**

I should have added some background information before posting this question.

The reason why I'm using C-style arrays is because I want to combine the high level vertex objects into a *vertex array* for rendering with OpenGL, which as far as I know requires a collection of raw arrays (`float[3]`) or structs.

For that purpose I think [user2079303's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37413824/192077) is the best option. However, if a more elegant solution exists that would be even better. :)

Comment: have you tried to add a conversion operator? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator

Comment: @Alex I have to disagree with the dupe.  It does not explain how to initialize an array type.

Comment: Do you have to have an raw array or can you use a `std::array`?

Comment: @NathanOliver I failed to mention that in the question. Some background info added now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A class cannot be convertible to a (raw) array, because the cast operator would have to return an array, which is not allowed in c++. Furthermore, arrays cannot be copy-initialized anyway.

What you can do is define an array, and pass it to a function that populates the array according to the contents of an object:

```
void Vertex::fill_arr(float (&arr)[3]) {
    arr[0] = x;
    arr[1] = y;
    arr[2] = z;
}

// usage
Vertex v(1, 2, 3);
float arr[3];
v.fill_arr(arr);
```

Another option is to use `std::array` which can be returned and copy-initialized normally.

Comment: Thanks! I accepted your answer because it includes the compile-time checking

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

class Vertex
{
public:
    Vertex( float x = 0,
            float y = 0,
            float z = 0)
    : x(x), y(y), z(z) {}

    operator array<float, 3>() const {
        return {x,y,z};
    }
    /* See @user2079303's answer for a compile-time check of the array dimension */
    void fillArray(float arr[3]) {
        arr[0] = x;
        arr[1] = y;
        arr[2] = z;
    }

    float x, y, z;
};

int main() {
    Vertex v(1,1.4,2);

    array<float, 3> arr = v;

    float arr2[3];
    v.fillArray(arr2);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        cout << arr[i] << " " << arr2[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/UtixcF)

[std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) is as efficient as using a C-style array, no performance is lost. You can also use `std::vector` instead.

You can't just return and copy an array, even in C. That's why if you absolutely want to use a C array, you have to have a function like `fillArray`.

Comment: Note that `fillArray(float arr[3])` can not detect at compile time that user has passed a too small array, which is a bit dangerous - it's identical to `fillArray(float arr[])` which is identical to `fillArray(float* arr`).

Answer (score 1):

You have many options, and it which you choose depends a lot on context. Here are four different ways to "convert" your vertex:

```
class Vertex
{
public:
    Vertex(float x = 0,
        float y = 0,
        float z = 0)
        : x(x), y(y), z(z) {}

    operator array<float, 3> () const {
        return {x, y, z};
    }

    array<float, 3> array_copy() const {
        return {x, y, z};
    }

    unique_ptr<float[]> c_array_copy() const {
        return unique_ptr<float[]>(new float[3]{ x, y, z });
    }

    void copy_into(float in[3]) const {
        in[0] = x;
        in[1] = y;
        in[2] = z;
    }

    float x, y, z;
};
```

First, you can just cast the class using the () operator:

```
cout << "Direct access" << endl;
auto as_array = (array<float, 3>)vertex;
cout << as_array[0] << as_array[1] << as_array[2] << endl;
```

Second, you can let copy semantics to some work for you with array_copy():

```
cout << "Get a copy" << endl;
auto as_copy = vertex.array_copy();
cout << as_copy[0] << as_copy[1] << as_copy[2] << endl;
```

Third, you can get a more c-style array copy with a unique pointer to a dynamically allocated array:

```
cout << "Get a c-style copy" << endl;
auto as_c_copy = vertex.c_array_copy();
cout << as_c_copy[0] << as_c_copy[1] << as_c_copy[2] << endl;
```

Finally, you can copy into an out-parameter:

```
cout << "Copy onto an out-parameter" << endl;
float copied[3];
vertex.copy_into(copied);
cout << copied[0] << copied[1] << copied[2] << endl;
```

As I say, which you choose really depends on context and performance requirements.

Note that in no case can you just return a c-style array.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a conversion operator to construct your array. Also I would suggest using a `std::array` instead of a raw array.

```
#include <array>

class Vertex
{
public:
    Vertex(float x = 0.0f, float y = 0.0f, float z = 0.0f)
    : x(x), y(y), z(z)
    {}

    float x;
    float y;
    float z;

    operator const std::array<float, 3>() const
    {
        return {x, y, z};
    }
};

int main()
{
    Vertex v(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    std::array<float, 3> arr = v;
}
```